# How to configure one to one optional relationship with FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1, ef-fluent-api

For a restriction of our architecture, the `Id` property can not be changed!

I have an employee class:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public virtual int Id {get; Set; } 
    public virtual int Matricula {get; Set; } 
}
```

And a user class (System User)

```
public class User 
{
    public virtual int Id {get; Set; } 
    public virtual int Matricula {get; Set; } 
    public virtual Employee Employee {get; Set; } 
}
```

The `Matricula` property in `User` class should be a FK pointing to the class `Employee` with the `Matricula` property.

The `Employee` property in `User` class represents the Employee object associated with the same `Matricula`.

How do I set this via Fluent API in EF?

The goal is that, if the `Matricula` in employee is the same of `Matricula` property in user, they must be associated and `Employee` class will be filled with this employee in `User` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do using EF. For One-to-one relationship `Matricula` have yo be `PRIMARY KEY` in both entities.